# Marketing Cloud - reporting on tracking params (UTM)

Tags: marketing-cloud

We currently track conversions based on UTM data and would like to be able to pull specific pieces of the UTM string into a Discover report field.

Example:
CTA URL is [www.test.com/&gps-source=test1&utm_medium=email&utm_source=exacttarget&utm_campaign=test1](http://www.test.com/&gps-source=test1&utm_medium=email&utm_source=exacttarget&utm_campaign=test1)

Can either the GPS source or UTM campaign from the URL be brought into a field in reporting?

Edit to add that we do also include the job id in the UTM campaign field but we have multiple sends under the same job id so that is unable to work as a differentiating field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible (at cost) to have [Send Time Attributes](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_di_send_time_attributes.htm&type=5) added to Discover reporting. Typically, if you're using the [Web Analytics Connector](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_overview_parameter_management.htm&type=5) the utm_campaign will be populated using [Additional Email Attributes](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000353527&language=en_US&mode=1&type=1). These can be logged to your [Send Log](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000333925&type=1&mode=1) data extension from where Discover can include the attribute in your reports.

Given Discover is due for [retirement in April 2022](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_rn_january_2021_discover_reports_retires.htm&type=5), you may find it unattractive to go through the process of paying for and provisioning Send Time Attribues, however.